# Prevent deleted to be search on searchbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to prevent the deleted Employee information to occur on my search bar as seen on the first picture [there are only 3 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAkgS.png) but when I put some numbers, [this deleted one appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Lya.png) the code I use is as follows: Thankyouuu!

```vb
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles empId.TextChanged
        Using db As New [Emme_Subic_Transport_Corporation_Payroll].EmmeSubicEntities
            Dim drivers = db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.EmployeeID.Contains(empId.Text)).ToList

            If drivers.Count() > 0 Then
                db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.isDeleted <> 1).Load()
                ' db.UserDetails.Load()
                UserDetailBindingSource.DataSource = db.UserDetails.Local
            Else
                MsgBox("No Match Found!")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not check it in the base WHERE clause?  `Dim drivers = db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.EmployeeID.Contains(empId.Text) && c.isDeleted <> 1).ToList`

Comment: You should move the query off the UI thread as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This does the Trick perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Include another condition in the where which filters out the deleted users. And run the query off the UI thread. Here is a simple way to run your query on a background thread, off the UI, and it will only run when 1 second passes without an additional keystroke in the textbox

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Static queryTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf runQuery, Nothing, -1, -1)
    queryTimer.Change(1000, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub runQuery(state As Object)
    Dim employeeID As String
    Me.Invoke(Sub() employeeID = empId.Text)
    UserDetailBindingSource.DataSource = Nothing
    Dim drivers As IEnumerable(Of UserDetails)
    Using db As New [Emme_Subic_Transport_Corporation_Payroll].EmmeSubicEntities
        drivers = db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.EmployeeID.Contains(employeeID) AndAlso Not c.IsDeleted).ToList()
    End Using
    UserDetailBindingSource.DataSource = drivers
    If Not drivers.Any() Then MsgBox("No Match Found!")
End Sub
```